# Group simple product with fixed price, without qty and user selection option

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom-options, module

Is it possible to combined together simple product with fixed price, without qty and user selection option, [Custom Option](http://magento.uservoice.com/forums/24441-magento-ecommerce-platform/suggestions/341595-add-a-new-product-type-that-groups-simple-products)??

Wanted to have feature like grouped product but without user interaction to select product, it should be sold as together with one single price.

Comment: you can create an other product with a different name and a different SKU